# Apache not initiating

Tags: apache, xampp, port

Here is my Apache log

> 11:47:46 AM  [Apache]     Attempting to start Apache app...
>
> 11:47:46 AM  [Apache]     Status change detected: running
>
> 11:47:46 AM  [Apache]     Status change detected: stopped
>
> 11:47:46 AM  [Apache]     Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
>
> 11:47:46 AM  [Apache]     This may be due to a blocked port, missing
>   dependencies,   11:47:46 AM  [Apache]     improper privileges, a crash,
>   or a shutdown by another method.
>
> 11:47:46 AM  [Apache]     Press the Logs button to view error logs and
>   check
>
> 11:47:46 AM  [Apache]     the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
>
> 11:47:46 AM  [Apache]     If you need more help, copy and post this
>
> 11:47:46 AM  [Apache]     entire log window on the forums

This is what happened recently. I am already using port 8080 for apache, I already configured the required configurations to 8080. I do not have Skype, I already disabled IIS. Can anyone tell me what might be wrong. Thank you.

Comment: Show us your error.log

Comment: Also, if you are seeing any error in Windows Event logs, paste it in your post.

Comment: There are no error logs dated today. The last error log was 3 days ago, and I already troubleshooted it. the error was always prompting but not recording in the error log. So I think need to configure something but I do not know what. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Restart your pc and try once. If its same change port (not to 80)

load XAMPP Control panel.

[image: image 01]

click apache `config`, then `httpd.conf`

then search `Listen 80` or go to line number 58.

Change that to `Listen 85`

Start XAMPP/Apache

So your localhost will be

`http://localhost:85/`

Comment: my localhost is already at port 8080 http://localhost:8080/ when I posted this. but starting apache still gives that error message. thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I tried to initialize it in the shell. And the error appeared from the shell. It was my network settings restarted and xampp is not directed to my static IP address.